# can xfce4-terminal set line-space ? Or which terminal-enumlator supports setting it?

Tags: terminal-emulator

`GVim` can achieve this goal by `set linespace=12`, but It does not work in `xfce4-terminal`.

I have tried almost all terminal listed in [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/list_of_applications#Terminal_emulators), but didn't find.

thanks for help!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/194264/how-do-i-change-the-line-spacing-in-terminal/983242 for more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I changed xfce4-terminal to `urxvt`

[similar question](http://segmentfault.com/q/1010000004086261)